# Xcode 7 Sprite Kit X Coordinate Off-Center in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios-simulator, xcode7

I just updated to Xcode 7 / Swift 2,  and I came across this problem, the x-axis in SpriteKit in iOS simulator seems to be off-center.  Someone please try this to verify, it is very simple.  Make a new SpriteKit Project in Xcode 7, and in the `touchesBegan` method, add this bit of code `print(location)` just underneath `let location = touch.locationInNode(self)` in the GameScene.swift file.

Then run it in iOS Simulator (any device, though I chose the iPhone 4s) and click around in the view while watching the results in the output.  The Y-axis is zero at the bottom, but the X-axis seems to be around 300 on the left, and increases as you go right.  I am losing my mind over this!

The whole `touchesBegan` method will look like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        print(location) // <-- *** ADD THIS LINE ***

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = location
        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)
        sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

Let me know if you can reproduce it, and why it is happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find **GameViewController.swift**, after find next chunk of code:

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

So there you have to add:

```
 scene.size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
```

after line:

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

that will solve your problem.
hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this next line in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` method of your GameViewController:

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

I added it right before the line `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill`. Did this fix the problem?

Comment: This solves my problem, but the boiler plate SpriteKit project template has the scene setup code inside `viewDidLoad()` not `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`.  Though some of my older projects have it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`.  I'm not sure if Xcode changed the template, or if I changed it myself and don't remember.  But as of Xcode 7.0.1 it is in `viewDidLoad()`.  But the real question is:  Why is this snippet suddenly necessary to make the project template work like it used to?

Comment: No. The problem is in the SpriteKit template. When the app calls the viewDidLoad method, the skView is not yet added to the main view, so its dimensions are not accesible yet (in `viewDidLoad()` you can't even know if the skView is in landscape or portrait). But if you set the dimensions inside the `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` you just made sure that the skView is already loaded into the main view, and now you can get its dimensions. Finally, I'm pretty sure you did that change yourself in your old templates, as it has always been necessary.